# how do increment all column values in db table after certain integer values in that column (django)?

Tags: python, django, django-database

Suppose I have created "X" database table in Django which has column id(autofiled), name(charfield) and occurrence(integerfield), now suppose 3 rows are already available in it

| id | name | occurrence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 1 |
| 2 | BCD | 2 |
| 3 | CDE | 3 |

I want to get data based on (ordering) the occurance number, I am facing a problem that, I want to add a row with an occurrence number 2 (already present), and all the rows with occurrence numbers greater than 2 update and increment automatically. (Basically, It is a inserting data on index number, where value is name and index is occurrence ignore id). For Example-

| id | name | occurrence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 1 |
| 2 | BCD | 3 |
| 3 | CDE | 4 |
| 4 | XYZ | 2 |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
    occurrence = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        same_occurrence = FooBar.objects.filter(occurrence=self.occurrence).first()
        if same_occurrence:
            same_occurrence.occurrence = self.occurrence + 1
            same_occurrence.save()
        return super(FooBar, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank You, Also I want to ask how can we do the opposite of the same like if I delete any row then all the occurrence column values below that row are decrement by 1?

Comment: Change the delete function and update the occurrence of items which should be decreased.

Answer (score 1):

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
    occurrence = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

> Try out this query

```
Foobar.object.filter(occurence__gte=sort_number).update(occurence=F('occurence')+1)
```

-> another way

```
        course = module.course
        modules = course.modules.all()
        module_for_update = []
        i = 1
        for module in modules:
            if module.pk == int(module_id):
                module.order = order
                module_for_update.append(module)
                continue
            if order == i:
                i += 1
            module.order = i
            module_for_update.append(module)
            i += 1
        Module.objects.bulk_update(module_for_update, ["order"])
```

Comment: This code doesn’t work. assume occurrence list be [1,2,3,5] with insertion of 3 your code change the list with [1,2,3,4,6] but that should be [1,2,3,4,5].

Comment: Then you have to loop and increment values